# Getting concatenated result from 2 LEFT JOIN mysql query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables:

Table1

```
| id | description     |  
|----|-----------------|  
| i1 | description1    |  
| i2 | description2    |  
| i3 | description3    |  
| i4 | description4    |
```

Table2

```
| id | group_id |  
|----|----------|  
| i1 | g1       |  
| i1 | g2       |  
| i2 | g2       |  
| i3 | g1       |  
| i3 | g3       |  
| i4 | g1       |
```

Table3

```
| group_id | group_name |  
|----------|------------|  
| g1       | group1     |  
| g2       | group2     |  
| g3       | group3     |
```

I'm looking for query to get result as:

```
i1 | description1 | group1,group2  
i2 | description2 | group2  
i3 | description3 | group1,group3  
i4 | description4 | group1
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` Aggregation formula and a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.description, group_concat(t3.group_name) 
FROM table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.group_id = t3.group_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.description
```

Comment: It worked well, thank you. Am I right - group_concat + GROUP BY - do the trick?

Comment: Yes. The `GROUP_CONCAT()` performs comma delimited aggregation and the `GROUP BY` specifies which columns will be grouped distinct.